# C# - Newly created variable of custom class does not exist

Tags: c#, class

I created a new class called DashObject, then immediately created an example DashObject. But when I try to access it, the IDE says it doesn't exist.

I'm trying to manage Amazon Dash devices using this class, but I can't even access them once defined for some reason.

```
    class DashObject
    {
        // Definitions
        string DashName; 
        string DashIdentifier;
        int DashFunction;
        string DashFunctionInfo;
        // Constructor
        public DashObject(string dashName, string dashIdentifier, int dashFunction, string dashFunctionInfo)
        {
            DashName = dashName;
            DashIdentifier = dashIdentifier;
            DashFunction = dashFunction;
            DashFunctionInfo = dashFunctionInfo;
        }
    }

    //Create example DashObject
    DashObject example = new DashObject("Example", "44650DFD85E9", 1, "prsl");

    //Attempt to access example (this line causes build to fail)
    MessageBox.Show(example.DashName);
```

Comment: What *exactly* does the IDE report?

Comment: The name 'example.DashName' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Then I suspect the issue is in some of the code you're not showing us - the code in your question is *incomplete*, you cannot have both a `class` declaration and the `MessageBox.Show()` statement in the same *scope*. Please try to create a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks - I completely forgot about the scope I was in. That solved it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a `public` or `internal` access modifier on it. Change your code to:

```
public class DashObject
{
    // Definitions
    public string DashName; 
    public string DashIdentifier;
    public int DashFunction;
    public string DashFunctionInfo;
    // Constructor
    public DashObject(string dashName, string dashIdentifier, int dashFunction, string dashFunctionInfo)
    {
        DashName = dashName;
        DashIdentifier = dashIdentifier;
        DashFunction = dashFunction;
        DashFunctionInfo = dashFunctionInfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message that the OP is quoting (in the comments) is CS0103, which I don't think is the error we get when it's an access issue.

Comment: While trying this new code, I noticed I was in the wrong scope and fixed it. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The name 'example.DashName' does not exist in the current context. means that either the name doesn't exist, or it is private, so menthods in another scope cannot find it.

Comment: No, that should generate error [CS0122](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha94aebs.aspx) which reads "'member' is inaccessible due to its protection level".

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen the error CS0122, I've only had CS0103?

Answer (score 0):

in order to access the field you must set it to `public` or `internal`:

```
public string DashName;
```

or

```
internal string DashName;
```